# VBA - BoxPlot diagram in Excel 2016

Tags: excel, vba, diagram, boxplot

I'm currently having a problem creating a boxplot chart in Excel

```
temp.Activate

With ActiveSheet
'First diagram
.Shapes.AddChart2(227, xlLine).Select

With ActiveChart
.SetSourceData Source:=ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 1), ActiveSheet.Cells(pEnd, 15))
.ChartTitle.Text = "Diagram 1"
.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = -30
.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = 25
.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Axe1"
.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Axe2"
.Axes(xlValue).Crosses = xlMaximum
.HasLegend = True
ActiveSheet.Shapes(ActiveChart.Parent.Name).ScaleWidth 3, msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft
ActiveSheet.Shapes(ActiveChart.Parent.Name).ScaleHeight 2, msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft
.ClearToMatchStyle
.ChartStyle = 230
End With

.Shapes.AddChart2(408, xlBoxwhisker, 200, 100, 350, 200, True).Select
With ActiveChart
.SetSourceData Source:=ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 1), ActiveSheet.Cells(pEnd, 15))
.ChartTitle.Text = "Diagram 2"
.HasLegend = True
ActiveSheet.Shapes(ActiveChart.Parent.Name).ScaleWidth 3, msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft
ActiveSheet.Shapes(ActiveChart.Parent.Name).ScaleHeight 2, msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft
End With 'Chart


End With 'temp
```

The first diagram is created without any problems. For the second chart, Excel reports the error: "Object does not support this action."

On the line:

```
.SetSourceData Source:=ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 1), 
ActiveSheet.Cells(pEnd, 15))
```

Is this a problem of the BoxWhisker diagram? Or did I incorporate an error

Thank you!

Best regards,
Timo

Comment: Can you show what the expected output would be for a small sample of input data please? You can use a [table generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) to format data and then add that between code tags.

Comment: @QHarr 
I can do that. I am surprised that the code does not work because I recorded it with Excel

Comment: Welcome to the world of the macro recorder! This can happen with macro recorded code I'm afraid. It is not uncommon.

Comment: | test1 | 2 | -3 | 1  | 2  |
|:-----:|---|----|----|----|
| test2 | 3 | -4 | -2 | -1 |
| test3 | 5 | 6  | 4  | 2  |

Comment: @QHarr and it should look like this: [boxplot](https://imgur.com/a/VqFXs)

Answer (score 1):

This can be simplified but for starters is it the right idea?

```
Option Explicit
Sub TEST()

    Dim temp As Worksheet
    Set temp = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Dim pEnd As Long

    pEnd = 3

    temp.Activate

    With ActiveSheet
        'First diagram
        .Shapes.AddChart2(227, xlLine).Select

        With ActiveChart
            .SetSourceData Source:=ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 1), ActiveSheet.Cells(pEnd, 15))
            .ChartTitle.Text = "Diagram 1"
            .Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = -30
            .Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = 25
            .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
            .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Axe1"
            .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
            .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Axe2"
            .Axes(xlValue).Crosses = xlMaximum
            .HasLegend = True
            ActiveSheet.Shapes(ActiveChart.Parent.Name).ScaleWidth 3, msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft
            ActiveSheet.Shapes(ActiveChart.Parent.Name).ScaleHeight 2, msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft
            .ClearToMatchStyle
            .ChartStyle = 230
        End With

        With .Shapes.AddChart2(408, xlBoxwhisker, 200, 100, 350, 200, True)

            With ActiveChart
                .SetSourceData Source:=ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 1), ActiveSheet.Cells(pEnd, 15))

                .ChartTitle.Text = "Diagram 2"
                .HasLegend = True
                ActiveSheet.Shapes(.Parent.Name).ScaleWidth 3, msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft
                ActiveSheet.Shapes(.Parent.Name).ScaleHeight 2, msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft
            End With

        End With                                 'Chart


    End With                                     'temp

End Sub
```

With test data

[image: Test data]

Comment: The boxwhisker diagram is generally pretty buggy. Maybe the element just does not work for that

Comment: Yes. The line chart works again but the BoxPlot chart does not contain any data

Comment: Maybe my Excel-Version is too old for the BoxPlot diagram? :/

Comment: This is with Excel 2016 and with my corrections for syntax seems to work. :-( What version you running?

Comment: Damn. I really do not know why that does not work for me :(

Comment: Excel 2016 16.0.4639.1000

Comment: Exact same as in your Screenshot

Comment: 16.0.4549.1000 64 Bit You are running a more up to date version.